# Fix this error? TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iterator

I am trying to find if a variable is in a list of keys of a dictionary inside a list. I did this using just a regular dictionary reference, but it didn't work.

I previously had all three of my dictionaries lined up, but it didn't work. Now they are all separated.

```
 if currentTurn == 1:
        while len(player1sequence1) != 5:
            addingCard = str(input("Type the code of the card you want to add to your sequence:"))
            if addingCard in player1Cards[0].keys:
                if player1Cards[0][addingCard] != 0:
                    player1Cards[0][addingCard] -= 1
                    player1sequence1.append(addingCard)
                else:
                    print("You ran out of that card. Try again.")
            elif addingCard in player1Cards[1].keys:
                if player1Cards[1][addingCard] != 0:
                    player1Cards[1][addingCard] -= 1
                    player1sequence1.append(addingCard)
                else:
                    print("You ran out of that card. Try again.")
            elif addingCard in player1Cards[2].keys:
                if player1Cards[2][addingCard] != 0:
                    player1Cards[2][addingCard] -= 1
                    player1sequence1.append(addingCard)
                else:
                    print("You ran put of that card. Try again.")
        print(player1sequence1)
```

I expected the result to add "addingCard" to the list 'player1sequence1", but it threw me this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Khang Nguyen/Attack Sequence text Based version.py", line 263, in <module>
    if addingCard in player1Cards[0].keys:
TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keys` is function, not property, so you should add `()`:

```
if addingCard in player1Cards[0].keys():
```

or even better:

```
if addingCard in player1Cards[0]:
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!